# How come I have a to call "global" to set a global variable in a Python function

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

```
def try_again():
    play_again = input("would you like to play again? ").lower()
    if play_again == "y":
        global comp_count
        comp_count = 0
        global user_count
        user_count = 0
        game()
    else:
        print(" Thanks for playing! Bye now! :) ")
        exit()
```

This is in Python 3. I'd like to reset a global variable in a function. How come I have to call it that way? Is there a better DRY way?

Comment: Because that is how it is supposed / defined to work. The better, cleaner way is to not have global variables.

Comment: @luk2302 I guess you don't agree with `try_again` being defined. That's a global variable.

Comment: Because you should not use global variables. Of course there are technical reasons for the need of `global` as well, but I do not know them or care, I do not use global variables and neither should you. Global state will only bite you at some point.

Comment: If `user_count=0` assigned global variables by default, then to assign variables local to the function you'd need an inverse `thisfunction inner_count`. Nobody wants that because local variables are WAY more common than global ones. As for `global user_count=0`, that seems plausible, but that's messier because it *seems* to allow for a local `user_count=2` to coexist. So which one do you use if you see something like `print(user_count)`? `global user_count` declares that the name is *definitely* global for clarity.

Comment: And the other commenters are right. You want functions to not depend on global variables so it can have reliable behavior given the input arguments. If you want to update a global `user_count`, instead of `try_again()` do something like `comp_count, user_count = try_again(comp_count, user_count)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a variable is made outside a function, it is set to global by default, but if you create a variable inside a function, and you want the variable to be accessed and changed by other functions, you set it to global.